# how to add library source in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

i can't seem to find in google/stackoverflow how do i add a library to my project using the library sources so that in make time it will compile the library and then my project and then link between them.

the library i'm trying to add is curlpp

as of now I've tried the following:

`add_library(curlpp STATIC IMPORTED ./curlpp)`

`target_link_libraries(myExec curlpp)`

```
link_directories(./curlpp/src/)
include_directories(./curlpp/includes)
```

but it has no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to [add the subdirectory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_subdirectory.html) to actually build the library, *then* you can add the actual library for linking.

If the library is not a CMake project you might need to add a simple `CmakeLists.txt` file in the library, that executes the actual configuration and building.

You might also use [custom commands](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_custom_command.html) from the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file to configure/build the library.

Answer (score 0):

Basing off on *Some programmer dude*'s response the following commands allowed me to statically link with curlpp:

```
add_subdirectory(./vendor/curlpp)
set_property(TARGET curlpp PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ./vendor/curlpp/libcurlpp.a)
target_link_libraries(my_target curlpp)
```